# Make python send the enter key when using curl

Tags: python, bash, curl

I'm making a python script that curls the fantasy hockey scoreboard page, calls a perl to regex substitute out the team names and scores, and display it. The regex is all set up, but now I'm having trouble getting the webpage. I notice when I do it on my computer after I run the

```
curl -o /tmp/fantasyhockey.txt http://games.espn.go.com/fhl/scor...
```

command, pressing enter once will start it, and then pressing it again will exit out and make my page. How do I force python to press enter? For my curiosity sake, why is it waiting?

EDIT: Here's the script. Not much to it.

```
import os
def main():

    os.system("curl -o /tmp/fantasyhockey.txt http://games.espn.go.com/fhl/scoreboar\
    d?leagueId=xxxxx&seasonId=2013")
    unfix = open("/tmp/fantasyhockey.txt", "r").read().replace('\n', '')
    outfile = open("/tmp/fantasyhockey2.txt", "w")
    outfile.write(unfix)
    outfile.close()
    os.system("perl regex.pl < /tmp/fantasyhockey2.txt")
    os.system("rm /tmp/fantasyhockey*")
main()
```

Comment: can you present the script that is doing the curl ?

Comment: included. There may also be a better way to use curl instead of forcing python to do something bizarre.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `&` character in your URL has special meaning in the shell (it sends the program to the background). This is why you have to hit enter.

To avoid this, quote the URL argument to `curl`, like this:

`curl -o /tmp/fantasyhockey.txt "http://...."`